# Proving a graph (that has $n$ vertices and contains an $n$-clique) is in $P$?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

I was looking at the Wikipedia article for the Clique Problem, and was curious if [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Cliques_of_fixed_size) can be applied to graphs when $k$ is equal to $n$? 
The run time would be $O( n^n)$, which is still polynomial, right?

Comment: No, and no. $n^{n+2}$ is ***not*** polynomial. However, for a graph with $n$ vertices, "contains an $n$-clique" is the same as "is an $n$-clique", and the run time is $O(n^2).$

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: There are $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ pairs of vertices. So the number of operations is $Cn(n-1)/2$ where $C$ is the number of operations it takes to check that one pair of vertices is joined by an edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression
$$ n^n = e^{n\log n} = (e^{n})^{\log n}$$

is not polynomial in $n$, but you are asking to decide if a graph is complete, which takes at most $\binom n 2$ steps, i.e. it's $O(n^2)$. 
 It may be interesting to know that the $k=\frac n2$ [case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/half-clique-np-complete-problem) can be shown to be NP-complete.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. Thank you so much! (and thanks for the edit!)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother you again (and also sorry if this isn't the appropriate place to ask this). I was curious as to where you got \binom{n}{2}. I looked more at complete graphs through Wikipedia and see that the number of edges is $n(n-1)/2$, which bof stated is equivalent to \binom{n}{2} above. Is there a way to derive \binom{n}{2} from $n(n-1)/2$, or is that kind of like a fact (sorry, I'm really terrible at math)? Can this method also work for instances such as the $k=n/2$ case you linked, but in P (like this problem) rather than NP-complete?

Comment: @CrazyCoder $$ \binom n2 \colon= \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{(n-2)!2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$ It is also the number of ways one can pick $2$ elements out of $n$ elements if one does not care about the order. This means that the complete graph has that many edges, because for any $2$ vertices you pick, there's exactly one edge, and you can pick $2$ vertices $\binom n2$ ways. To somewhat answer your last question, I feel that finding $k$-cliques should be the same as finding $n-k$ cliques in complexity.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, I see where n choose 2 came from now. Awesome! Thanks again for the explanation and your time!

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sure thing :)